# How to use a parameter from another build job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My Jenkins pipeline contains calling another build job like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            when {
                branch 'develop'
            }
            steps {
                build job: 'deploy-to-develop-stack', parameters: [string(name: 'STACK_NAME', value: "develop-stack")]
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

The downstream job is started but I have no idea how it can access the parameter `STACK_NAME`.

I tried with `$STACK_NAME`, `${STACK_NAME}` but none of this works.

It works if I enable "This project is parameterized" but this will ask for a user input which I want to avoid as the parameter shall be passed in from another pipeline script.

**Update #1**
My fallacy... please see my own answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a fallacy. Activating "This project is parameterized" is the way to go. The user input is, of course, not requested if the parameter is passed from another pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) which will let you pass parameters from one task to another.

You need also add this parameter you passed from upstream in downstream

Answer (score -1):

```
  build job: "deploy-to-develop-stack",
    parameters: [
      [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'STACK_NAME', value: "develop-stack", description: 'develop-stack'],

    ];
```

This should be helpful

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you explain a bit what he's doing wrong? All code answers are not recommended